# Prevent NServiceBus from processing messages in the input queue

Tags: nservicebus

I want to configure an NServiceBus instance in order to use the `SendLocal` method, which works fine using the following code:

```
var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
    .StructureMapBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .PurgeOnStartup(true)
    .UnicastBus()
        .LoadMessageHandlers()
        .DoNotAutoSubscribe()
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();

 bus.SendLocal(new MyMessage());
```

However, doing this causes the message to be immediately processed. I would like the bus  to not process the message but handle it in another AppDomain later using another NServiceBus instance.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bus.Send(msg) to another NServiceBus endpoint, when the NSB instance starts up, it can process the message.

Note, You need to configure the endpoint of another service in you app config like following

```
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MYCO.Messages.MyMessage" Endpoint="MyMessage.Another.Endpoint@localhost"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Comment: That's what I came up with as well, thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that before. I even have the separate AppDomain so that I can use custom settings for it.